# Simpler Javascript counter

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help with the click event, I'm trying to have an individual counter that is incremented by the click event that I have on the img. I've tried many variations, I want to resolve this without using jQuery.

```
    <script async>

    var count = 0;

    var clickerCount = document.getElementsByClassName('clicker');
    var cat = {
        count : 0,
        counter: function(){
            this.count++;
            clickerCount.textContent = "Kitten Click Count :" + this.count;
            console.log("counter function working");
            console.log(cat.count);
        }
    };

    function modifyNum(){
        cat.counter();
        console.log("modifyNum function working");

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="display:inline">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id="cat0" onclick="modifyNum();">
        <p id='clicker'>Kitten Click Count :</p>

    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id='cat1' onclick="modifyNum();">
        <p id='clicker'>Kitten Click Count :</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should work. I've separated the HTML from the Javascript because it looks clearer for me. You can use it as an example to expand / create your own in your own way.

Hope it help

HTML:

```
<div style="display:inline">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id="1" class="countable">
        <span>Kitten Click Count :</span><span id="counter-for-1">0</span>

    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id="2" class="countable">
            <span>Kitten Click Count :</span><span id="counter-for-2">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var imagesCountable = document.getElementsByClassName("countable");
var counters = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imagesCountable.length; i++) {
    counters[imagesCountable[i].id] = 0;
    imagesCountable[i].onclick = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("counter-for-" + e.currentTarget.id)
        .innerHTML = ++counters[e.currentTarget.id];
    }
}
```

```js
var imagesCountable = document.getElementsByClassName("countable");
var counters = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imagesCountable.length; i++) {
    counters[imagesCountable[i].id] = 0;
    imagesCountable[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var cElem = document.getElementById("counter-for-" + e.currentTarget.id);
        cElem.innerHTML = ++counters[e.currentTarget.id];
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id="1" class="countable">
        <span>Kitten Click Count :</span><span id="counter-for-1">0</span>

    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id="2" class="countable">
            <span>Kitten Click Count :</span><span id="counter-for-2">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is good, I wish I could've came up with this on my own. Can you explain why you have the counters array wrapping the images countable.

Comment: @alphapilgrim it is about this line? `counters[imagesCountable[i].id] = x`?

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you are using `id='clicker'` in two places (IDs are supposed to be unique), and then using `document.getElementsByClassName`, which returns nothing because you used an ID and not a class.

Once you do change it to a class, `document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array of elements. You'll have to use `clickerCount[0]` and so on, or loop through the array.

Comment: thanks for the help, although Im still unsure of how to increment the the count individually. Also I cant seem to get the actual count on the screen. Id like for cat0 and cat1 to have different counts.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cesarzapata/cuLso1L2/)!

If you can hardcode the IDs then it's easier in my point o view to just manipulate things by ID.

```
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/296" id="cat0" onclick="counter(0);">
        <p id='clicker0'>Kitten Click Count :</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="counter0" value="0">
    </div>


function counter(id) {
        var cnt = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter" + id).value);
        cnt++;
        document.getElementById("counter" + id).value = cnt;
        document.getElementById('clicker' + id).innerHTML = 'Kitten Click Count :' + cnt;
}
```

It's not the same approach but I find it easy to understand.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first off you have two elements with the id of 'clicker'. You probably meant for those to be classes and ids. So when you call modifynum() it cant locate those because the class doesn't exists. Second, your JS is loading before your HTML elements. So when the JS gets to this line:

```
var clickerCount = document.getElementsByClassName('clicker');
```

It is going to find nothing, even if you correct the class names. So you want to move your JS to the footer of your HTML document, or wrap the code in a method that is called on pageLoad().

I *think* that should take care of it. Your object, for the most part, looks correct.

Comment: I forgot to mention the part @Sam brings in his answer about the array of clickerCount.

Comment: I tried writing an if statement to check if the click.event was for the specific cat and still not working. Im still unsure of how to increment the the count individually. Also I cant seem to get the actual count on the screen. Id like for cat0 and cat1 to have different counts. I tried making two variable for counters to increment. Still no go.